# How to call Background Fetch iOS with multiple intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background-process, background-fetch

In my iOS application i want to make an api call for every 4 hours.

As of my research i found that it can be achieved by background task or Local notification or Push Notification.

As of my knowledge, By Notifications (Either Local or Push both) user have to interact with application.

I want to make an api call without user interaction, even app is in background or foreground or active.

I didn't get exact sample code for background fetch which works with  intervals.

Some one please guide me in this issue.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the interval here or specified a minimum fetch interval (The smallest fetch interval supported by the system) like this example:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}
```

For 4 hours:

```
NSTimeInterval fourHours = 14400;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:fourHours];
```

Comment: The background method has 30seconds to complete the task before UIBackgroundFetchResult to the completionhandler function.